# Python Django forms replaces old inputs

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am currently trying to impliment a registration form but everytime I test it out, the new registrant replaces the old registration. So I am unable to have more than one user at a time.

any help would be great because I do not know what to do. Thanks.

My views:

```
def register_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        new_user = bitcoinUser(first_name=cd['first_name'], 
                               last_name=cd['last_name'],
                               phone_number=cd['phone_number'])
        new_user.save()
```

my models:

```
class bitcoinUser(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     phone_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: can you post your models.py?

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know why that didn't work (I think it is because you are saving the object 'new_user' and not the form), but i will recommend the way that i do forms in Django:

models.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Bitcoinuser(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    phone = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class BitcoinuserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bitcoinuser
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone']
```

views.py:

```
from .models import BitcoinuserForm

def get_bitcoinuser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BitcoinuserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/database/')

    else:
        form = BitcoinuserForm()

    return render(request, 'appname/get_bitcoinuser.html', {'form': form})
```

It's simple, straigthfoward and works fine.

Comment: I tried this but it failed out because of the form.save()... 'RegistrationForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: Did you import ModelForm? `from django.forms import ModelForm`

Comment: I tried it with ModelForm and it didnt return the form as valid, it failed the "if form.is_valid()" check

Comment: Strange, did you copied my code or just changed yours? Double check everything (look for typos and small errors) and refer to the official documentation for eventual debuging: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/